# Getting raw HTML and re-rendering it as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a script to rewrite the local version of the ETrack system my college uses as it's horrific, and I have a bit of an issue with formatted text. You see, there's a div on this system with the class `.visitFeedback`, and in this Div it has loads of `<p>` tags. I want to move these paragraphs into a scrollable div due to the paragraphs overflowing normally. The only issue is, these paragraphs have HTML styling within them (`<strong>` etc.). I want to reserve this formatting and just add it into a scrollable Div. So far I've managed to move it over, but all the methods I've tried so far return stuff like `[object HTMLParagraph]` instead of the text I want. So far I've tried `.get()`, `.html()`, `.text()`, and a few others. Can you please help? The relevant stuff is below:

```
var feedbackTxt;

    $('.visitFeedback p').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('info'))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            feedbackTxt += $(this).text();
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });

    $('.visitFeedback').append('<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">' + feedbackTxt + '</div>');
```

Comment: feedbackTxt += will give undefined the first time. Setup var to be a string: var feedbackTxt="";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not add `overflow-y: scroll` to elements with the `.visitFeedback` class?

```
$('.visitFeedback').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel quite embarrassed I didn't contemplate that :). I'll mark as answer ASAP